# UISplitViewController with modal segue not rotating

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I've created a project from the master detail template in Xcode 4.2/iOS5. I am trying to preform a modal segue from the splitviewcontroller. I call the following from my detailviewcontroller.m:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.splitViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayLoginView" sender:self.splitViewController];
}
```

The login view shows fine but it does not rotate and stays in portrait. Any ideas on how to get it to autorotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by implementing a custom class for the destination view controller and adding the
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method making sure it returned YES.